# c++ inserting and sorting "empty" array at the same time

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I am still learning C++, so please if this is a duplicate point me to correct topic as I couldn't find any good and useful explanation.
I try to create a function in my ascending_ordered_array class which will insert elements into "empty" array sorting them in the same time.
Below is my code so far, but unfortunately it doesn't work 100% correctly as it adds two largest numbers as a last for positions in array.

```
void ascOrderedArray::push(Datatype p_item, Datatype* p_array, int p_size)
{
    int i, j = 0;
    int temp, num;
    if (p_array[j] < 0)
        p_array[j] = p_item;
    for (i = 0; i < (p_size - 1); i++)
    {
        num = p_size;
        for (j = (p_size - 1); j >= i; j--)
        {
            if (p_array[num]> p_array[j])
               num = j;
        }
        temp = p_array[num];
        p_array[num] = p_item;
        p_array[i] = temp;
     }
 }
```

Here is part of main which call function above trying place random numbers into it

```
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
     num = (i + 1)* (rand() % 100);
     arr.push(num, arr, size);
  }
```

any hints what I am missing out?

Comment: Is this function simply supposed to insert the given item into the given array, maintaining the sort order in the process? And if so, how do know the top-end capacity *and* current fill-size of the array?

Comment: Is this example for learning c++ or a real application? If it is the latter, you could use some STL containers like a std::set, which will do the sorting for you.

Comment: @WhozCraig : yes it should insert element into given array in a correct order, ascending in this case. if by top-end capacity you mean size of array it is specified when array is created

Comment: @MatthiasB this is learning example, unfortunately, it have to be an array

Comment: Couldnt you just do this by iterating through the array once finding the correct index for the new element and then move everything after that position one pos forward and insert your new element at its correct position? If you do it that way you cant presume that the array is always sorted so there is no need sorting it again every time you insert an element. The current complexity is always n^2 doing this approach you would lower it to 2n.

Comment: does that have any impact on that push/insert function if it is placed in .h file and it is part of the custom array class?

Comment: @szarleydwarf This is only a possible approach if push is the only method adding elements to the array since this is the only way you can ensure that the list is always sorted.

Answer (score 0):

This is code I wrote and its work as long as it is no resize neccessary

```
 void ascOrderedArray::push(Datatype p_item)

{
    //check if array is big enough and resize it if necessary
    if (m_numElements >= m_size)
        resize();

    //checking if array contains some elements and if not set its first to pased item
    if (m_numElements == 0)
    {
        m_array[0] = p_item;
        m_numElements++;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        int i = m_numElements;

        while (i >= 0 && i <= m_numElements)
        {
            //shifting array elements
            m_array[i] = m_array[i - 1];

            if (p_item > m_array[i - 1])
            {
                m_array[i] = p_item;
                break;
            }
            --i;
        }
        m_numElements++;
    }
}
```